# Scalar product after processing the vectors

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In a spreadsheet, I have several rows given in column pairs. In the first row, only the even columns are of interest. In the other rows, I need first to process each row by column pairs (odd column and next even column). After this, I only need to do a scalar product of the values in the first row with the output of the processed rows.

To put things in short, assume I have a 3x6 matrix (50x24 in reality):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |  | 20 |  | 30 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 |

I want:

```
= A$1*foo(A2,B2) + C$1*foo(C2,D2) + E$1*foo(E2,F2)
```

where `foo` is a macro function with two scalar inputs and one scalar output.

So far I have tried:

```
= SUM.PRODUCT({A$1;C$1;E$1};foo({A2;C2;E2};{B2;D2;F2}))

= SUM.PRODUCT({A$1;C$1;E$1};{foo(A2;B2);foo(C2;D2);foo(E2;F2)})
```

and other similar alternatives, all give me error. I know how to do it in a dozen of languages, but to me this one is pure necromancy.

For instance, this is a simple Julia snippet for the task,

```
foo(x,y) = x*y
M = [60 missing 20 missing 30 missing; 3 2 5 4 2 4; 0 0 2 3 3 1]
odd  = 1:2:size(M,2)
even = 2:2:size(M,2)
[ dot( M[1,odd] , foo.(M[j,odd],M[j,even]) ) for j = 2:size(M,1) ]
```

which returns

```
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1000
  210
```

Only MS Excel, only LO Calc, and only GG Sheets solutions are welcome, but a compatible MS Excel and LO Calc is preferred.

Comment: My guess would be to modify `foo` to accept and return arrays. Sounds like premature optimization though. What's wrong with typing out the remaining terms in the first formula?

Comment: Not sure I understand `foo`, do you want to return an array or single value? What do you expect it to output and what's the data? Currently it's all vague.

Comment: Here's my guess . . . `=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(A1:F1,,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:F1)/2,0,2),,1)),MAP(OFFSET(A2:F2,,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A2:F2)/2,0,2),,1),OFFSET(A2:F2,,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A2:F2)/2,1,2),,1),LAMBDA(a,b,foo(a,b))))`

Comment: @BigBen, @P.b (or @P-b), and @Domenic, thx for the comments. I have improved the description: I have specified the input/output arguments of `foo` and given a simple snippet example. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @Domenic, you got more or less the idea. I am gonna work on your answer, but first I need to look in Libre Office's help for the description of the functions you use. As a starter, I think SEQUENCE is not available in Libre Office. Thx, though.

Comment: @BigBen I need it to work on both, MS Excel and LO Calc.

Comment: It would have been best to specify that earlier, and there's no guarantee that there's a solution that works for both.

Comment: To be fair, I don't know how to refer to MS Excel's language and I just realized that MS Excel, GG Sheets and LO Calc do not share the same set of functions. I would expect that such a simple problem should have a common solution. Again, spreadsheets are necromancy to me.